# get signal from eye neurons

Tags: neurophysiology

Hi guys you know some scientists could get electronic signals from brain and move it to muscles ([full article here](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/04/14/health/paralysis-limb-reanimation-brain-chip.html?_r=0))

My question is: can we get signal from eye neurons and analyze it with a computer and after that see what he/she/it is seeing?

If somebody did this research will you please give me an article about that?

Comment: Have a look at this video: https://www.ted.com/talks/mary_lou_jepsen_could_future_devices_read_images_from_our_brains The method they use do not measure activity directly from the neurons but measure the BOLD response (oxigination of blood in brain areas).

Comment: That's just what I need thanks a lot How can I use this algorithm to convert signals to pictures?

Comment: That i do not know. You should check if she has some publicized research which you could refer. I bet there is a ton of research on it.

Comment: Sounds great if you know something else H will be happy if you say it to me

Comment: Do you mean from outside the head or would using electrodes inserted inside the body somehow count?

Comment: I want to use electrodes inserted inside the body

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people study the neural code of the retina. The output from retina are the retinal ganglion neurons (RGC). Their input-output relation and circuits are well modeled (but not fully understood).

Usual preparation is to put retina harvested from an animal on an electrode array and record their responses to movies. See references below:

1. Baden, T., Berens, P., Franke, K., Román Rosón, M., Bethge, M., and Euler, T. (2016). The functional diversity of retinal ganglion cells in the mouse. Nature, 529(7586):345-350.
2. Field, G. D., Gauthier, J. L., Sher, A., Greschner, M., Machado, T. A., Jepson, L. H., Shlens, J., Gunning, D. E., Mathieson, K., Dabrowski, W., Paninski, L., Litke, A. M., and Chichilnisky, E. J. (2010). Functional connectivity in the retina at the resolution of photoreceptors. Nature, 467(7316):673-677.
3. Pillow, J. W., Paninski, L., Uzzell, V. J., Simoncelli, E. P., and Chichilnisky, E. J. (2005). Prediction and decoding of retinal ganglion cell responses with a probabilistic spiking model. Journal of Neuroscience, 25:11003-11013.